# In PYCHARM imports work fine but give me an error while running the module from CLI

Tags: python, import, directory, structure

I am newbie to programming. I am importing a function from a.py to b.py
(i.e from pkg.subpkg1.a import func) but it give me an error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg')

directory structure:

```
root-dir
       /pkg
           /subpkg1
                a.py
           /subpkg2
                b.py
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something called **__init__.py** that will mark directories on disk as Python package directories. so that you can access other py files
[Sample Dir Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x68VB.jpg)

**a.py contains**

```
print("I am a.py")
```

**and b.py contains**

```
import a # here you should mention parent directory
print("I am b.py")
```

running **b.py** will give you,

```
I am a.py
I am b.py
```

Comment: every package contain the __int__.py but still it doesn't work from CLI. it works fine in pycharm. @Dhamodharan

Comment: Since we are using systems default interpreter and the directory structure got changing. just change  **bold**from pkg import subpkg1 **bold** to **bold**import subpkg1**bold** . then run subpkg2 , python will autometically create compiled version of subpkg1 & you may see "_pycache_" folder.

Comment: still didn't work for me

Comment: Please check this demo https://github.com/dhamodharanrk/examples/tree/master/PackageDemo